# sql query that will show the intersection of the same elements in each day

Tags: sql, mysql, pandas

I need an SQL query for the next question.
For example I have a table:

```
| id       | element  | dt       |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1        | a        | 22/04/22 |
| 2        | a        | 22/04/22 |
| 1        | b        | 27/04/22 |
| 1        | a        | 23/04/22 |
| 3        | b        | 22/04/22 |
| 1        | a        | 22/04/22 |
| 1        | a        | 22/04/22 |
| 3        | b        | 23/04/22 |
| 3        | b        | 25/04/22 |
| 1        | a        | 27/04/22 |
| 1        | c        | 26/04/22 |
| 1        | d        | 26/04/22 |
| 1        | g        | 25/04/22 |
| 1        | b        | 27/04/22 |
```

I want to find the percentage of similar items that the user (id) sees in one week (but not counting on the same day). For example, for this table, the answer is:

```
| id       | percentage |
| -------- | ---------  |
| 1        | 0.3        |
| 2        | 0.0        |
| 3        | 1          |
```

for id 1 answer is 0.3, because if we are taking a window for one week (7 days) he has seen an element "a" 3 times at 22/04/22, 23/04/22 and 27/04/22. He seen "a" at 22/04/22 a few times, but we don't counting it. At he seen 10 times at total. So answer is 3/10 = 0.3

I tries smth like this, but it doesn't solve my problem exactly.

```
SELECT
  dt,
  id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT element) AS total,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT element)
    FROM table newt
    WHERE newt.dt = dt
  ) AS same_day_elements,
  COUNT(DISTINCT element) / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT element) FROM table tempt WHERE date = tempt.date) * 100 AS percentage
FROM
  table t
GROUP BY
  dt,
  id
```

Comment: I haven't down voted but I'll hazard a guess. 1. Your sample data contains `dt` column which is not formatted as a valid date. If anyone wants to mock your scenario they would have to hand type all the dates. 2. Your explanation is unclear. What would the result be if 1 had seen both "a" and "b" on three distinct dates? Or "a" on three dates and "b" on four? 3. Your explanation with percentage `3/10 = 0.3`, surely as a percentage this should be 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on Chris's answer, with the subquery containing counts for distinct date and all rows for each id, element group:

```
SELECT id, ROUND(SUM(IF(dd > 1, dd, 0)) * 100 / SUM(total), 0) AS percentage
FROM (
    SELECT id, element, COUNT(DISTINCT dt) AS dd, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM t
    WHERE dt BETWEEN '2022-04-22' AND '2022-04-28'
    GROUP BY id, element
) t
GROUP BY id;
```

Output:

| id | percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 100 |

In the comments above you extended your question with:

> what if I have data for a year and I need to look not only at one week?

It is not completely clear what you want for this, but assuming you want to group by week, you could add week number ([WEEK(date[,mode])](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)) to both the inner and outer groupings:

```
SELECT id, weekno, ROUND(SUM(IF(dd > 1, dd, 0)) * 100 / SUM(total), 0) AS percentage
FROM (
    SELECT id, element, WEEK(dt, 1) AS weekno, COUNT(DISTINCT dt) AS dd, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM t
    WHERE dt BETWEEN '2022-01-03' AND '2023-01-01'
    GROUP BY id, element, weekno
) t
GROUP BY id, weekno;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/epNDXMce)

Answer (score 0):

You should think in terms of first collapsing your data set and then performing your calculations on that reduced data set.  The problem becomes a whole lot easier.  So, first count all the id-element combinations, then embed it in a calculation:

```
Select id,sum(Case When occurrences>1 Then 1 Else 0 End) *100/count(*) as percentage 
From (
    Select id,element,count(*) as occurrences
    From table
    Where dt between '2022-04-22' and '2022-04-28'
    Group By id,element
)
Group By id
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I have data for a year and I need to look not only at one week?

Comment: Also, if I understand correctly, if an element met 4 times during the week on different days, then you will count as one. And I would like to get something like a formula:

(Number of matching items on different days) / (all rows with this id)